# Web crawler - how to build the visited url set?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, web-crawler, shared-memory, distributed-computing

I have implemented a distributed web crawler on rabbitMQ. Everything is almost done except the visited url set. I want to have some kind of shared variable between different crawlers.

Furthermore, as I have been reading, the size of this url set will be huge and should be stored in disk.
What is the best way to store, access and share this visited-urls list in a distributed environment?

Answer (score 1):

As majidkabir says, Nutch is quite a good solution...but that doesn't answer the question since it's about how to track state when building your *own* crawler.

I'll offer the approach I took when I created a crawler in Node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-nutch). As you can see from the name, the approach I've taken is in turn modelled on the approach taken in Nutch.

All I did was to use the URL as the key (after normalising), and then store a simple JSON file in S3 that contained the state of the crawl. When it was time to run the next crawl I'd whizz through each of these JSON files looking for candidates to be crawled and then after retrieving the page, set the JSON to indicate when to crawl next.

The number of pages I was crawling was never very large so this worked fine, but if it did get larger I'd put the JSON into something like ElasticSearch and then search for URLs to be crawled based on a date field.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, any storage that is scalable and supports indexing can be used for such use cases.

Some of the systems that I know are being used for such purposes are [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/), [Redis](https://redis.io/) or any SQL databases that can scale.

I have used Redis for the same purpose and I have been storing approximately 2 millions of URLs. I am quite sure, by increasing the nodes I should be able to scale easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) for crawling, this library has ability to crawl url in a specific period and use some algorithms for this purpose.
For example: When a page with specific url don't changed in second crawling nutch increase the period of next crawling and if it changed, decrease this period.
You can create your own nutch plugin for parsing the data that nutch crawled or using predefined nutch plugins.